# python-lambda mixed with MikTex

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to use the package python-lambda to work with Amazon Web Services.

I installed it as follows:

```
pip install python-lambda
```

After that I tried to initialize the function with

```
lambda init
```

However, I started receiving weird MikTex errors. I suspect that somehow the name "lambda" has been reserved already for some LaTex or Miktex functions, which I suppose are not relevant for the package python-lambda. Is this true?

The error I get are:

> This is Omega, Version 3.14159--1.15 (MiKTeX 2.9.6300 64-bit)
>   Copyright (c) 1994--2000 John Plaice and Yannis Haralambous
>
> Sorry, but lambda did not succeed.
>
> The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going
>   again:

And in the log file:

> You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
>
> 2019-01-09 15:35:27,300+0100 FATAL lambda - The memory dump file could
>   not be found. 2019-01-09 15:35:27,300+0100 FATAL lambda - Info:
>   fileName="lambda.fmt" 2019-01-09 15:35:27,300+0100 FATAL lambda -
>   Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp 2019-01-09
>   15:35:27,300+0100 FATAL lambda - Line: 691 2019-01-09
>   15:36:25,984+0100 INFO  lambda - starting with command line: lambda
>   init 2019-01-09 15:36:26,017+0100 INFO  lambda - going to create file:
>   lambda.fmt 2019-01-09 15:36:26,584+0100 ERROR lambda -
>   C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
>   2.9\miktex\bin\x64\initexmf.exe did not succeed; exitCode: 1 2019-01-09 15:36:26,584+0100 ERROR lambda - output: 2019-01-09
>   15:36:26,584+0100 ERROR lambda - Running miktex-omega.exe... This is
>   Omega, Version 3.14159--1.15 (MiKTeX 2.9.6300 64-bit) (INIOMEGA)
>
> Copyright (c) 1994--2000 John Plaice and Yannis Haralambous
>
> ("C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
>   2.9\tex\lambda\config\lambda.ini"
>
> ("C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
>   2.9\tex\lambda\base\lambda.tex"
>
> ("C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
>   2.9\tex\latex\base\latex.ltx"
>
> ! LaTeX requires e-TeX.
>
> l.98     {LaTeX requires e-TeX}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lambda is part of the Miktex Package Omega.
You have two possibilities:
1) if you don't need Omega uninstall miktex-omega and miktex-omega-bin
2) change the order in your PATH environment variable or remove the miktex path from the variable in your console when executing python scripts

up to you